# Unit Testing using ezyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, enzyme

can anybody please explain me the Difference between the two packages `enzyme` and `jasmine-enzyme`...

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import jasmineEnzyme from 'jasmine-enzyme';
```

I want to know how differently they work. I couldn't found any promising answer  in my research

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enzyme is a JavaScript Testing utility for React. But it doesn't have inbuilt assertions functions. It relies on external testing libraries such as Mocha, Chai, Jasmine for assert functions.

`jasmine-enzyme` is an assertion library for `enzyme`. It uses `jasmine` like syntax for assertions. Similarly there are other options such as `chai-enzyme`, `should-enzyme`, `expect-enzyme`.